# Stored XSS. JSP. taglib tag

Tags: java, jsp, security, xss, taglib

**Given**

```
// Java abstract code
labelName = '<script> alert('xss'); </script>'
// JSP
<%@ taglib uri="org.company.tag.tagobject" prefix="tagobject" %>
<tagobject:labelName/>
```

**Expected result**

JSP shows string properly without accidental JavaScript code activation

**Actual result**

JSP taglib tag activates JavaScript (thus can be easily used for XSS)

```
// Result from code at the start
shows alert with text xss
```

I tried:

```
<c:out value="<tagobject:labelName/>" />
<c:out value="${fn:escapeXml(tagobject:labelName)}" />
```

But it doesn't work.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. taglib file tags.tld:

```
<tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
<jsp-version>2.2</jsp-version>
<short-name>org</short-name>
<uri>org.company.tag.tagobject</uri>
<tag>
    <name>labelName</name>
    <tag-class>org.company.tag.LabelName</tag-class>
    <attribute>
        <name>plural</name>
        <required>false</required>
    </attribute>
    <body-content>empty</body-content>
</tag>
</taglib>
```

2. java class LabelName:

```
private void writeDescriptor (String descriptor) throws JspException, IOException {
    final JspWriter writer = getJspContext().getOut();

    writer.print(descriptor);
}
```

3. jsp file home.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="org.company.tag.tagobject" prefix="tagobject" %>
<tagobject:labelName/>
```

4. write something into string variables of that tagobject, so they are used as descriptors and shown at jsp.

Part 2 String descriptor already contains string representation of JavaScript, so that probably I can filter JavaScript code there.
Probably c:out or fn:escapeXml can be used there but I'm not sure how. Also I'm not sure which code is needed to explain better.

**First solution**

I've tried to filter string on part of Java custom tags (step 2, in java class LabelName). Found library for this named *owasp-java-html-sanitizer*.
So, now LabelName class looks like this:

```
private void writeDescriptor (String descriptor) throws JspException, IOException {
    final JspWriter writer = getJspContext().getOut();
    String safeString = new HtmlPolicyBuilder().toFactory().sanitize(descriptor);
    writer.print(safeString);
}
```

Have not checked all the possible xss inputs but at least it *removes* simplest ones i've checked.

Comment: Forgive me if I am the one being unintelligent here - but how is this security related? To me, this looks like a question for StackOverflow or CodeReview Ex, most likely SO rather than CR though.

Comment: @JoshuaJones This code results into XSS. And usual XSS prevention methods are not working. Thus i'm asking security-related people about how to make this code safe. If this is more for SO - then i will create question there

Comment: The problem with us telling you how to make the code safe is we don't do code review, whilst we help with security-related things if you're asking for us to review your code and help you improve it, we don't do that. In-fact it's probably better suited to CodeReviewEx however I have never used that Ex so I don't know the guidelines.

Comment: @JoshuaJones Ok, thanks for explaining. Then i will use another resource :)